# Remove newlines from each line of a text file that contains links and display those links in an iframe

Tags: php

```
$myFile = "text.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);

$link1 = $lines[0];
$link2 = $lines[1];

<!-- 1 -->
<iframe src="<?php echo $link1?>" width="100%" height="50" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
    your browser do not support iframes.</iframe>

<!-- 2 -->
<iframe src="<?php echo $link2?>" width="100%" height="50" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
    your browser do not support iframes.</iframe>
```

this is how it displays in google chrome view source:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOzOV.png
this is how it looks in the website, it isn't loading:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziX0f.png

what's the problem with the code?

Comment: You may need to trim 'end of the line' from the link variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line to:

```
$lines = file($myFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Using this flag, new lines at the end of each line will be **removed**.

Comment: it worked for the line thanks! but iframe is still not loading i don't know why, it's showing refused to connect.

Comment: Try to open developers console in your browser, maybe there're some hints.